# Wie sagt man "To gather one's thoughts" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verb, verb-usage

Ich habe zwei Verben gefunden, die zu diesem Kontext passen, aber ich bin nicht sicher, ob sie richtig sind:

> aufsammeln
>
> sammeln

Wenn ich Sätze damit bilde, weiss ich nicht, ob sie Sinn machen werden :

> Ich werde dir später von meiner Vergangenheit erzählen, weil ich noch meine Gedanken auf/sammeln muss.

Wenn es irgendwelche Möglichkeiten dafür gibt, lässt es mir bitte Bescheid sagen.

Comment: _Ich muss **mich** erst **sammeln**_ ist sehr ähnlich.

Comment: Man kann *sich sammeln* oder gar *seine fünf Sinne zusammennehmen* oder  *seine Gedanken ordnen* oder einfach (gebräuchlicher) *nochmal drüber nachdenken*

Comment: Eigentlich gibt dir Carsten S die korrekte Antwort, da er auf deine Frage eingeht. Portree Kid hat zwar recht, gibt dir aber nur eine Alternative während deine Frage ja eine berechtigte ist :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gedanken ordnen wird in dem Zusammenhang sehr oft benutzt.

> Ich werde dir später von meiner Vergangenheit erzählen, weil ich noch
>   meine Gedanken ordnen muss.

Answer (score 8):

„Gedanken sammeln“ ist richtig, und Du wirst viele Beispiele bei Google finden. Aufsammeln würdest Du Gedanken nur, wenn sie auf dem Boden zerstreut wären. Schönes Bild eigentlich ;)

Comment: Ja, aufsammeln hat direkt einen nicht metaphorischen Beigeschmack und nutzt man wirklich eher pragmatisch